# Does bounding a certain power series from above bound its coefficients from above?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

[Note: Rolled back to previous version, before I edited it.  This question was poorly posed and didn't cover the cases I had in mind.  See [this new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264796/conditions-to-bound-a-power-seriess-coefficients-from-above).]

Let—$$f(x) = \sum_k a_k x^k, \text{ and } g(x) = \sum_k b_k x^k,$$ be functions that map [0, 1] to [0, 1].  The functions are infinite convergent power series with non-negative coefficients.

Then is $g(x)$ bounded above by $f(x)$ only if $b_k$ is bounded above by $a_k$ for every $k$?  Is this result known?

For example, I note that $\exp(x/4)/2$ and $\exp(x/2)/2$—

- are bounded above by $\sum_k (1/2)(1/2)^k x^k$, which is the probability generating function of a geometric(1/2) random variable, and also
- have coefficients that are bounded above by that generating function,

which is why I suspect this is a more general phenomenon.

Comment: If you only consider boundedness on the interval $0\leq x\leq 1$, then the answer is definitely no. Consider $a_1=1$, $a_i=0$, $i \neq 1$ and $b_2 = 1$, $b_i=0$, $i\neq 2$. Then $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$, so $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for $0\leq 1$, however the sequences $a$ is not bounded from above by $b$.

Comment: It does not even need to be restricted to $[0,1]$. Compare $f(x)=1+x^2$ and $g(x)=x$ and the coefficients of $x$. You have $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ even though $a_1 < b_1$

Comment: @Henry: Your counterexample doesn't cover the cases I have in mind.  I have edited the question.  In any case, this is redundant with the answer given.

Comment: It makes no difference. Just add $3+x+e^x$ to both to give decreasing positive coefficients to both and  to ensure non-polynomial non-rational functions.  So  $f(x)=4+x+x^2+e^x$ and $g(x)=3+2x+e^x$ and all your conditions are satisfied and you have $f(x) >g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ but $a_1 <b_1$

Comment: @Henry: In that case, my question was poorly posed and has been accepted.  You should add your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take for instance $f(x)=x,\;g(x)=x^2$. Then $g(x)$ is bounded above by $f(x)$, but $b_2=1$ is not bounded above by $a_2=0$.